# OCI - using OCIIOV with scattered buffers

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

So, OCI (Oracle user interface) has a data structure named OCIIOV which is basically a buffer and a its length.

The even give an example (The entire example: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci05bnd.htm#BABGDJDD)

```
char  buf_1[NUM_BIND][LENGTH_DATE], 
char  buf_2[NUM_BIND * 2][LENGTH_DATE], 


/* The define buffers */
bvec[0].bfp = buf_1[0];                       /* Buffer address of the data */
bvec[0].bfl = NUM_BIND*LENGTH_DATE;           /* Size of the buffer */
```

In the example above the `char` buffer is continuous but I want to use scattered   memory (so I won't allocate so much data, but only the amount I actually need).  Is there a way to do so? I tried to use `OCIBindByPos` with maximum buffer size (I thought it would do `strlen()` to get the actuall string length) but this method doesn't work (reads invalid memory).

Is there a solution for scattered buffers?

Comment: I'd advise you to try either array-binding or dynamic-binding rather than OCI_IOV. I've used both successfully, while I never tried OCI_IOV, and since they provide the same performance benefit, use that instead.

Comment: @ddevienne - Yes - that what I ended up with